# Android phone as serial slave?

Tags: android, serial-port, android-2.3-gingerbread

Is there a way to connect an Android phone to a computer as serial port?

I've found several libraries etc. ([this‎](https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/) and [this‎](https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/)), but they all seem to really on Android 3.1 or higher (I have 2.3.4) and all seem to be a serial host.

So my question: Would it be possible to use my Android phone (2.3.4) as a serial slave?

Thanks in advance.